# GWT - Update Widget when java.util.List changes

Tags: java, gwt

I am making AsyncCalls and they fill some collections (java.util.List) with data. These callbacks take quite a time, so by the time collections are filled, UI is fully loaded.

However, widgets that are supposed to show data don't show anything. Because when they were initialized, collections were still empty.

Now I need to force my collection to somehow tell my widget *'hey I have that data for you, feed yourself!'*, but I don't know how. I was thinking of some **observer** pattern, but I am not really sure.

How can I solve this issue? An example would be nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data binding should be done in the callback. So your widget should either have a setData() function or if you want to keep it in the constructor the widget will have to be initialized once you get the callback.

Following the [GWT Doc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/AsyncCallback.html):

```
 service.getCollection(dbName, new AsyncCallback() {
   public void onSuccess(Items[] result) {
     // Fill the data (result) here
   }

   public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is to use [MVP pattern](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html).